# How to resolve jQuery issue?

Tags: jquery

I keep getting an error message when trying to create a menu item, stating that there is a jQuery. Can someone help me discover what the issue is?

I have tried to use Firebug but can't work out what the issue is.

When creating articles or modules it states the following:

> A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. You can stop the script now, open the script in the debugger, or let the script continue.

Script: http://www.gingerduck.co.uk/media/jui/js/jquery.min.js:2

Comment: It's not the jQuery.js that's really the problem, it's how you use that library in your code. Suggest you use non minified version of jQuery.js to try and pinpoint which part of jQuery is being used, so you can then back track to seee where you are using that method

Comment: I'm really sorry, but can you give me an idiots guide to what you just said? I'm new to this. I'm currently using joomla.

Comment: No I really can't other than go to jQuery.com, get a copy of the development version (for debugging ) and use that instead of the one you are using now which is `minified`. Then look in that file on the line where error gets thrown to find out what part of the library is being used when it does happen. Look in google what that term means

Comment: Can we see your code that uses jQuery? The link you have supplied is just a copy of jQuery, and does not really tell us very much about the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `:2`, this gave me an response code of 404 in the browser when added to the url.

The jQuery script itself looks correct.

Comment: That `:2` is a line reference in console where error is thrown within that file

Comment: I checked the jQuery file using [Diff Checker](https://www.diffchecker.com/) and it is identical with another jQuery v1.11.2 min file i had down to the 5th line. [Please redownload the correct  jQuery version](https://code.jquery.com/jquery/) and replace it with yours and try again.

Comment: Open http://www.gingerduck.co.uk/media/jui/js/jquery.min.js and look at the first line, its a comment including the version

Comment: Ok this may sound silly, but where do I place the code?

Comment: Not silly at all. You have to replace the file itself. go to where `jquery.min.js` is and delete that file, paste the newly downloaded version and rename it `jquery.min.js`.